# Amend script to select active document rather than running for all open docs as it does currently

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'Sub InsertImagesAllDocuments()

    Dim n, c As Integer
    n = Application.Documents.Count
    c = 1

    Dim r As Range

    Windows(c).Activate


    Do
        Dim imageFullPath As String
        Dim FindText As String
        imageFullPath = "C:\Logo.png"
        FindText = "?????"
        With Selection
            .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

            With .Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = FindText
                ' Loop until Word can no longer
                ' find the search string, inserting the specified image at each location
                Do While .Execute
                    Selection.MoveRight
                    Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=imageFullPath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
                Loop

            End With
        End With

        c = c + 1

        On Error Resume Next
        Windows(c).Activate

    Loop Until c > n

    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "?????"
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
        Wrap:=wdFindContinue
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is not Visual Basic .NET, it's Visual Basic 6.

Comment: VBA is to VB.NET as *car* is to *carpet*.

Comment: @CypherPotato : More correctly, it is VBA _(Visual Basic for Applications)_ - a macro language based on Visual Basic used in Microsoft Office.

Comment: @DavidMountford : You forgot to ask a question. Please take a moment to read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [Markdown and Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). This is not a valid question in its current state since it lacks a lot of information.

Answer (score 0):

use with ActiveDocument

```
With ActiveDocument
    ' do stuff
End With
```